# Hadoop Multi-Cluster Installation: Unable to see the data nodes despite seeing daemons running on them

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to set of a multi-node hadoop cluster using Hadoop 3.0.0. There is no straightforward documentation on this so I had to read a lot of blogs. I am at a point where when I run `start-all.sh` I see daemon processes appearing in the name node as well as data nodes. However, when I go to http://namenode:9870 I see 0 live nodes.

To be more specific when I run `start-all.sh` I see 
[image]

and I when I run jps I see NameNode, SecondaryNameNode and ResourceManager processes are running. On data nodes running jps shows DataNode and NodeManager are running.

What I get on the url is 
[image]

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Don't use `localhost` in a cluster. Use the hostnames or IPs. Even if the service runs on the machine it starts on 2) Did you copy `hdfs-site` and `core-site` and `yarn-site` from the namenode / resourcemanager to the datanodes, or did you just start the datanodes on their own?

Comment: Also, did you setup the slaves file? http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Slaves_File

Comment: Check the firewall on all the machines to make sure datanode & namenode can reach each other.